# Force disk cache even if guest uses direct i/o

Tags: performance, hyper-v, db2, cluster-shared-volumes

Have IBM `db2` on `Rhel` on `Hyper-V` on `Windows Server`.
The *.vhdx file is on `CSV`. e.g. `C:\ClusterStorage\volume1\hyper-v\oktest-lb1\oktest-lb1.vhdx`.

db2 uses `O_DIRECT` flag (uncached i/o) for its database files, and a small block size 8k or less for read/write operations.

Somehow this direct flag is propagated through the whole stack to the host system. The host cache is not used.

The network lag kills performance of such small operations. tested with dd with `oflag=direct` / `iflag=direct`

- bs=8k: 12Mbytes/s
- bs=64k: 100Mbytes/s

Need a workaround.